# Function Parameters Argument calculation with Input field value

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

i am trying to calculate the input value and function parameters values but i am not able to solve enter code updated in jsfiddle

input values + function `parameter values -here whatever we enter in the input box should calculate with parameters given..

code updated in jsfiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/siddineni/aygss97t/1/

please help me

Comment: function param will be `Mouse Click Event`, which you cannot sum.

Comment: @dav Every function has implicit object called `arguments` which holds all arguments passed to it irrespective to params specified within `()`.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/aygss97t/3/ check if this is what you requires?

Comment: Please explain what  are the possible input values and what is the expected result for them. Why in your fiddle are you running your function like `sumAll(values, 49, 100)` although it doesn't take any arguments in it declaration?

Comment: thankyou Agam.. so we have to run the function via closure ? as per ur fiddle ?                 correct me if i am wrong..completly new to js.. if you can explain your fiddle shortly would be helpfull...what mistake i had done ? did i called the functioality directly ? should i do by closure

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_arguments_sum                                                here is the example which i tried to plus the values by input values